# How does this has_member class template work?

Tags: c++, sfinae, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to understand how the following class template works (taken from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/e5fbc9305539f699?pli=1)), but I couldn't understand it properly:

```
template <typename Type> 
class has_member 
{ 
   class yes { char m;}; 
   class no { yes m[2];}; 
   struct BaseMixin 
   { 
     void operator()(){} 
   }; 
   struct Base : public Type, public BaseMixin {}; 
   template <typename T, T t>  class Helper{}; 
   template <typename U> 
   static no deduce(U*, Helper<void (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::operator()>* = 0); 
   static yes deduce(...); 
public: 
   static const bool result = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(deduce((Base*)(0))); 
};
```

More specifically, I don't understand the purpose of `BaseMixin` and the presence of `operator()` in it. Also, since `Base` is derived from it, I don't understand it as well.

Even more specifically, when template parameter `Type` has defined `operator()`, why *only* then SFINAE is triggered, causing the first `deduce()` function to be ignored and the second one is chosen?

---

Anyway, this is my test code:

```
struct A{};                             //SFINAE is triggered for A
struct B{ void operator()(){} };        //SFINAE is not triggered for B
struct C{ void operator()(int,int){} }; //SFINAE is not triggered for C

int main() 
{       
   std::cout << std::boolalpha; //enable true/false instead of 1/0!
   std::cout << has_member<A>::result << std::endl;
   std::cout << has_member<B>::result << std::endl;
   std::cout << has_member<C>::result << std::endl;
}
```

Output([ideone](http://ideone.com/wWpaP)):

```
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `BaseMixin` has an `operator()` definition.
- `Base` derives from both `Type` and `BaseMixin`, so if `Type` has an `operator()` then name lookup on `Base::operator()` will be ambiguous.
- `deduce` is called for `Base*`, not `Type*`.
- `Helper<void (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::operator()>` will only instantiate if `&U::operator()` unambiguously resolves to `BaseMixin::operator()`.
- Conversely, if `Helper<void (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::operator()>` does *not* instantiate, it's because `Type` has its own `operator()` making name lookup on `&U::operator()` ambiguous, and consequently the overload of `deduce` returning type `yes` is chosen.

Standard citation regarding the second bullet — C++11 §10.2/2-6:

> 2 The following steps define the result of name lookup for a member name `f` in a class scope `C`.
>
> 3 The *lookup set* for `f` in `C`, called *S(f,C)*, consists of two component sets: the *declaration set*, a set of members named `f`; and the *subobject set*, a set of subobjects where declarations of these members (possibly including *using-declaration*s) were found. In the declaration set, *using-declaration*s are replaced by the members they designate, and type declarations (including injected-class-names) are replaced by the types they designate. *S(f,C)* is calculated as follows:
>
> 4 If `C` contains a declaration of the name `f`, the declaration set contains every declaration of `f` declared in `C` that satisfies the requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs. [ *Note:* Looking up a name in an *elaborated-type-specifier* or *base-specifier*, for instance, ignores all non-type declarations, while looking up a name in a *nested-name-specifier* ignores function, variable, and enumerator declarations. As another example, looking up a name in a *using-declaration* includes the declaration of a class or enumeration that would ordinarily be hidden by another declaration of that name in the same scope. —*end note* ] If the resulting declaration set is not empty, the subobject set contains `C` itself, and calculation is complete.
>
> 5 Otherwise (i.e., `C` does not contain a declaration of `f` or the resulting declaration set is empty), *S(f,C)* is initially empty. **If `C` has base classes, calculate the lookup set for `f` in each direct base class subobject *B<sub>i</sub>*, and merge each such lookup set *S(f,B<sub>i</sub>)* in turn into *S(f,C)*.**
>
> 6 The following steps define the result of merging lookup set *S(f,B<sub>i</sub>)* into the intermediate *S(f,C)*:
>
> - If each of the subobject members of *S(f,B<sub>i</sub>)* is a base class subobject of at least one of the subobject members of *S(f,C)*, or if *S(f,B<sub>i</sub>)* is empty, *S(f,C)* is unchanged and the merge is complete. Conversely, if each of the subobject members of *S(f,C)* is a base class subobject of at least one of the subobject members of *S(f,B<sub>i</sub>)*, or if *S(f,C)* is empty, the new *S(f,C)* is a copy of *S(f,B<sub>i</sub>)*.
> - **Otherwise, if the declaration sets of *S(f,B<sub>i</sub>)* and *S(f,C)* differ, the merge is ambiguous: the new *S(f,C)* is a lookup set with an invalid declaration set and the union of the subobject sets.** In subsequent merges, an invalid declaration set is considered different from any other.
> - Otherwise, the new *S(f,C)* is a lookup set with the shared set of declarations and the union of the subobject sets.

Comment: Please quote the spec to support this : *Base derives from Type first, then BaseMixin (so if Type has an operator(), that will hide/shadow the one in BaseMixin)*. I want to see it myself.

Comment: @Nawaz : After reading the standard citation a couple times, I realized my rationale was wrong. Edited again.

Answer (score 2):

`Base` can inherit `operator()` from `Type`, or from `BaseMixin` and if `Type` has `operator()` it hides `BaseMixin`'s operator.

So, if `Type` has no `operator ()` defined, `Base`'s `operator()` can be casted implicitly to `BaseMixin`'s `operator()`. Then, `deduce(U*, Helper<void (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::operator()>* = 0)` with `U==Base` will match.

Oppositely, if `Type` has `operator()` defined, `Base`'s `operator()` cannot be casted to `BaseMixin`'s one, so `deduce(U*, Helper<void (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::operator()>* = 0)` will not match.