# How to define type trait for containers with index operator?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae, type-traits

I have the following type traits to distinguish between fundamental and container types:

```
template <typename T>
using enable_if_fundamental_t = std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>>;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_container<
      T
    , std::void_t<
          typename T::value_type
        , typename T::size_type
        , typename T::allocator_type
        , typename T::iterator
        , typename T::const_iterator
        , decltype(std::declval<T>().size())
        , decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())
        , decltype(std::declval<T>().end())
        , decltype(std::declval<T>().cbegin())
        , decltype(std::declval<T>().cend())
        >
    > : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_container_v = is_container<T>::value;

template <typename T>
using enable_if_container_t = std::enable_if_t<is_container_v<T>>;
```

and they are used with the following functions:

```
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_fundamental_t<T>>
void foo(T)
{
    std::cout << "This is a fundamental type" << std::endl;
}

template <typename C, typename = enable_if_container_t<C>>
void foo(const C& c)
{
    std::cout << "This is a container type" << std::endl;
}
```

with the following arguments:

```
std::list<std::uint32_t> l;
std::vector<std::uint32_t> v;
std::map<std::string, std::uint32_t> m;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::uint32_t> um;
std::uint32_t i = 42;

foo(l);
foo(v);
foo(m);
foo(um);
foo(i);
```

and they work fine.

Now I want to distinguish containers which has overloaded `operator[]` from the others. I tried the following code:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_container_with_index_operator_with_size_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_container_with_index_operator_with_size_type<
      T
    , std::void_t<
          enable_if_container_t<T>
        , decltype(std::declval<T>().operator[](std::declval<typename T::size_type>()))
        >
    > : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_container_with_index_operator_with_size_type_v =
    is_container_with_index_operator_with_size_type<T>::value;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_container_with_index_operator_with_key_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_container_with_index_operator_with_key_type<
      T
    , std::void_t<
          enable_if_container_t<T>
        , typename T::key_type
        , decltype(std::declval<T>().operator[](std::declval<typename T::key_type>()))
        >
    > : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_container_with_index_operator_with_key_type_v =
    is_container_with_index_operator_with_key_type<T>::value;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_container_with_index_operator_v =
    is_container_with_index_operator_with_size_type_v<T> ||
    is_container_with_index_operator_with_key_type_v<T>;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_container_without_index_operator_v =
    is_container_v<T> &&
    !is_container_with_index_operator_v<T>;

template <class T>
using enable_if_container_with_index_operator_t =
    std::enable_if_t<is_container_with_index_operator_v<T>>;

template <class T>
using enable_if_container_without_index_operator_t =
    std::enable_if_t<is_container_without_index_operator_v<T>>;
```

with the following overloads:

```
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_fundamental_t<T>>
void foo(T)
{
    std::cout << "This is a fundamental type" << std::endl;
}

template <typename C, typename = enable_if_container_without_index_operator_t<C>>
void foo(const C&)
{
    std::cout << "This is a container type without index operator" << std::endl;
}

template <typename C, typename = enable_if_container_with_index_operator_t<C>>
void foo(const C&)
{
    std::cout << "This is a container type with index operator" << std::endl;
}
```

with the same arguments as above, bit it produced me the error:

> error C2995: 'void foo(const C &)': function template has already been defined

I tried several variations of the code above, but I didn't manage to do it the right way.

How to do this the right way and is it possible to achieve a simpler code? For example without separate meta functions for containers which use `size_type` and `key_type` for the `operator[]`?

I'm using **Visual Studio 2017** version **15.7.2** with **v141** toolset and enabled `/std:c++17`.

Comment: In the "true" specializations of the `is_container_with_index_operator_with_`... templates, did you mean to use `enable_if_container_t` rather than `is_container_t`?

Comment: @aschepler Actually both of them works after I tested them.

Comment: But using `is_container_t`, it will match if I define a class that has a `size_type` and `operator[]` but is missing other container requirements like `begin`.  Putting `is_container_t<T>` inside `void_t` always successfully instantiates an `is_container_t` specialization that inherits either `false_type` or `true_type`, then discards it.

Comment: +1 Yes, you are correct. Now I see that the former incorrectly matches `std::array` event it has no `allocator_type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you can't overload functions based on default template parameter values alone. You can reproduce that with:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) > 2)>> void foo() {}
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!(sizeof(T) > 2)>> void foo() {}
// error: redefinition of 'template<class T, class> void foo()'
```

A possible solution is to use `enable_if_t` in a type of a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) > 2), int> = 0> void foo() {}
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!(sizeof(T) > 2), int> = 0> void foo() {}
```

Or in return type:

```
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) > 2)/*,void*/> foo() {}
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<!(sizeof(T) > 2)/*,void*/> foo() {}
```

---

Comment: +1 10x it works like a charm, but what about code simplification? Is it possible to treat containers with `operator[](size_type)` and `operator[](key_type)` the same way?

Comment: Hm. I'm wrong. It compiles but it still gives me incorrect results for all standard map types `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_multimap`.

Comment: @bobeff Then maybe the conditions you specify for `enable_if` are incorrect? It works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1858aebea5122718). As for detecting `operator[]`, I suggest a neat trick described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393938/find-out-if-a-c-object-is-callable (this one is for `()`, but it's trivial to adapt for `[]`)

Comment: I added `, typename T::key_type` to the `is_container_with_index_operator_with_key_type` before `, decltype(std::declval<T>().operator[](std::declval<typename T::key_type>()))` and already it works for `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, but I don't understand why this is needed? `std::multimap` and `std::unordered_multimap` actually have not overloaded `operator[]`.

Comment: @bobeff Check aschepler's comment under your question. `is_container_t` there has no effect because it's always a valid type. It has to be `enable_if_container_t` instead.

Comment: I corrected the example according to the aschepler's comment but I still don't see why separate `typename T::key_type` is needed after I have it on the next line?

Comment: @bobeff Have to tried to remove it after the correction?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't match `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` to have `operator[]` without the additional line.