# How Do I Correctly Help the C++ Compiler Deduce Lambda Param/Return Types?

Tags: c++

I'd like to iterate over a container, applying some transform to each item, and return the transformed item. In this case, I'm inserting them into a stringstream for output.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// concatenate the items iterated over
template<typename InputIt, typename T, typename V>
std::string ixjoin(InputIt begin,
                   InputIt end,
                   std::function<V(T)> xform,
                   const std::string & separator)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;

    if(begin != end) {
        ss << xform(*begin);
        begin++;
    }

    while(begin != end) {
        ss << separator;
        ss << xform(*begin);
        begin++;
    }

    return ss.str();
}



int main() {
    std::vector<int> list1 { 1,4,9,16 };
    std::vector<bool> list2 { true, true, false, false, true, false, true };

    std::cout << ixjoin<decltype(list1.begin()),int,int>(list1.begin(), list1.end(), [](int i){return i*i;}, ":") << "\n";
    std::cout << ixjoin<decltype(list2.begin()),int,int>(list2.begin(), list2.end(), [](bool b){return !b;}, ":") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This example is function, but I'd rather not have to specify all the template parameters. If I leave out the template parameters in the function call, the compiler doesn't find a matching overload for `ixjoin`. Is there a way to do this in which the types could be deduced?

Is there a good way to declare something as an iterator type so that its return value would be deduced automagically? E.g. `template<typename IteratorType, typename IteratorValue>` where `IteratorValue` is cleverly deduced? I rather lazily used `InputIt` for an iterator, but's not really anything smart.

It seems plausible that I shouldn't have to do more than specify the type of the return value of the `std::function<>`. Perhaps something like:

```
ixjoin<int>(list1.begin(),list1.end(),[](int i){return i*2;},",")
```

How can I do this The Right Way™?

Note: I tagged the question C++14, but I can be flexible. If there's a much better way in C++17 or C++20, that would be useful information.

Comment: Are you looking for "deduction guides" maybe? This *might* help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: Why do you even care about `T` and `V`? The usual way is to accept anything callable. Just make the type of `xform` a template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way :

```
template<typename InputIt, typename C>
std::string ixjoin(InputIt begin, InputIt end, C xform, const std::string & separator)
```

The harder way - use `enable_if` to check if C is [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393938/find-out-whether-a-c-object-is-callable).

Comment: `enable_if` sounds tempting until I see some example solutions using it. I guess I'll run without seat belts for now.

Answer (score 4):

Following the pattern of `std::transform`, I'd write this as

```
// concatenate the items iterated over
template<typename InputIt, typename UnaryOp, typename S = std::string>
S ixjoin(InputIt begin, InputIt end, UnaryOp xform, S separator)
{
    std::basic_ostringstream<typename S::char_type> ss;

    if(begin != end) {
        ss << xform(*begin);
        begin++;
    }

    while(begin != end) {
        ss << separator;
        ss << xform(*begin);
        begin++;
    }
return ss.str();
}
```

You can pass a lambda directly. There's no need for a `std::function`.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to using `std::function` (other than it's unnecessary)?

Comment: @mojo It uses type erasure and is "heavy".

Comment: @mojo: Well, as you discovered, `std::function` requires that you specify return type and argument(s). That's a disadvantage.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, "heavy" in terms of performance, memory, or what? Can you elucidate?