# is_callable emulation in C++14: update on old question

Tags: c++, c++14, functor

Looking a trait to tell if a class can be used as a callable, whatever the call parameters, I found this interesting post: [Find out whether a C++ object is callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393938/find-out-whether-a-c-object-is-callable).

I found this trait more powerful than `std::is_invocable`, in some use-cases, because it
does not need assumptions on the function call operator parameters.

Yet the accepted answer, inspired from [Member detection idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Member_Detector) requires that the tested type can be inherited.

Is it possible to extend the solution to non-inheritable types?

EDIT

My try:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct is_callable : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_callable<
    T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::operator())>::value, void>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

But if this classic SFINAE solution seems OK with a single `operator()` ([Live OK](https://godbolt.org/z/hbnM47Wrx)) it cannot work of there is several overload of the operator ([Live KO](https://godbolt.org/z/PE6Yqaado)) (whereas the answer of the linked post can): `&T::operator()` is ambiguous in the presence of overloads.

Comment: do you need this solution to be supported in C++14?

Comment: Yes. But as, it is a slightly different functionality than ```std::is_invocable```, seeing more modern implementations will interest me also.

Comment: What good is it to know that something is callable with _some_ set of arguments, if you don't know what set of arguments that is?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm.  I've added the C++14 tag to the question.

Comment: Actually it's more out of pure curiosity. The technic used demonstrates interesting properties, IMHO, about pointer to member function syntax. By extending the solution, I hope to learn technics that may be useful in other more realistic use-cases.

Comment: Note that a class type is callable without any `operator()` if it has a conversion operator to a function reference / pointer

Comment: @Oersted: So you don't really need a solution; you're just hoping that you'll learn something that might be useful in the future?